# API Request URL returns "Invalid Access"

Tags: api, web-scraping, browser

I'm trying to scrape data from a website but I have no experience with scraping or APIs except for making a Discord Bot once. So I followed the steps described here to find the API:
http://www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api

The Request URL in the Headers tab with the important information is this one:
https://api.amiami.com/api/v1.0/item?gcode=FIGURE-119023&lang=eng

When I try to open this page, like he does, it only returns:
{"RSuccess":false,"RValue":{"HttpStatusCode":400},"RMessage":"Invalid access."}

If you want to try getting the Request URL yourself, the original page I used was:
https://www.amiami.com/eng/detail/?gcode=FIGURE-119023

Removing the language argument doesn't seem to change anything either. So I guess there's something that detects that I'm not accessing it in a normal way. Any Ideas on how to fix this?